# Exporting public key into binary in pycrypto

Tags: python, rsa, pycrypto

I'm using python 2 with pycrypto and generating my keys like that.

```
random_generator = Random.new().read
self.parent.private_key = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator)
self.parent.public_key = self.parent.private_key.publickey()
```

And I've got a problem with getting a public key which I need to send as binary/base64 
I have searched whole RSA pycrypto lib and there are no methods that can convert my public into binary.

Can someone take a look and try to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `_RSAobj.exportKey(self, format='PEM', passphrase=None, pkcs=1)` function to serialize the the key (`_RSAobj` is the implementation of the key objects). If you use DER format it will use a binary encoding instead of the textual encoding of PEM. When using DER you might need to encode it using Base64 too.

You can then deserialize it using `RSA.importKey(externKey, passphrase=None)`.